# Can't install php7.2-ldap extension in Laradock

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laradock

I am trying to install `php7.2-ldap` in Laradock and I've set

```
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LDAP=true
```

and

```
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_LDAP=true
```

and then tries to build the image like

```
docker-compose build workspace
```

And I get this error message. Part of the log

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php7.2-ldap
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
Need to get 23.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 101 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 php7.2-ldap amd64 7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-ldap_7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
ERROR: Service 'workspace' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c if [ ${INSTALL_LDAP} = true ]; then     apt-get install -y libldap2-dev &&     apt-get install -y php${PHP_VERSION}-ldap ;fi' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

What's happening here and why can't I install this?

Answer (score 4):

I am answering my own question.

This was fixed by adding

```
apt-get update -yqq && \
```

before

```
apt-get install -y libldap2-dev && \
```

in `workspace/Dockerfile` and `php-fpm\Dockerfile`.

A complete block will look like this:

File: `workspace\Dockerfile`

```
###########################################################################
# LDAP:
###########################################################################

ARG INSTALL_LDAP=false
ARG PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_LDAP} = true ]; then \
    apt-get update -yqq && \
    apt-get install -y libldap2-dev && \
    apt-get install -y php${PHP_VERSION}-ldap \
;fi
```

**Why did this happen?** 
A quote from Github [issue](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1534):

> What appears to be happening here is that there are a few apt-get
>   install commands for several packages are called while the local
>   package repo is out of sync with the remote. In an interactive
>   environment, this would be seen by the user and an appropriate apt-get
>   update would be run. However, the Dockerfile does not contain any
>   package repo update commands, as such the current layer has a
>   different package repo list than the remote. This is in general the
>   "problem" with dockers layers as they will be re-used if their command
>   didn't change (something I, too, had to learn the hard way).

By: [Philipp Tempel](https://github.com/philipptempel)